# Add values to missing by id (key)

Tags: variables, stata

I'm trying to figure out how to fill missing values by a key value in Stata.

For example:

[image: Table]

I would like to fill the values in the new variable called `value_fill`, by the given number in `id`.

Comment: Please do ***not*** post screenshots. Read [How to create high quality reproducible examples in Stata](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377015/) for help on how to provide us with example data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
clear

input id value
1 100
1 .
2 102
2 .
3 .
3 .
3 103
4  .
4 104
4 .
end

bysort id (value): generate value_fill = value[1]

list, abbreviate(15) sepby(id)

     +-------------------------+
     | id   value   value_fill |
     |-------------------------|
  1. |  1     100          100 |
  2. |  1       .          100 |
     |-------------------------|
  3. |  2     102          102 |
  4. |  2       .          102 |
     |-------------------------|
  5. |  3     103          103 |
  6. |  3       .          103 |
  7. |  3       .          103 |
     |-------------------------|
  8. |  4     104          104 |
  9. |  4       .          104 |
 10. |  4       .          104 |
     +-------------------------+
```